# How can I run my asyncronous functions in order in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an action like this:

```js
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/userInfo`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          const userInfo = _.map(snapshot.val(), (val, uid) => {
            return { ...val, uid };
          });
          console.log(userInfo);
          dispatch({ type: USERINFO_FETCHED, payload: userInfo });
        });

        Actions.main();

        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
          payload: user
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        });
      });
  };
};
```

These functions run unordered because these are asyncronous functions. Alright we  all know that. I want to put in order these functions. First of all I want to run and finish this codes:

```js
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/userInfo`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          const userInfo = _.map(snapshot.val(), (val, uid) => {
            return { ...val, uid };
          });
          console.log(userInfo);
          dispatch({ type: USERINFO_FETCHED, payload: userInfo });
```

and after finish them I want to run this line:

```js
Actions.main();
```

Is that possible? I couldn't do it. Thank you for your answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix would be, trying something like `Actions.main();` this inside the `.on('value'`.

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/userInfo`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          const userInfo = _.map(snapshot.val(), (val, uid) => {
            return { ...val, uid };
          });
          console.log(userInfo);
          dispatch({ type: USERINFO_FETCHED, payload: userInfo });
          Actions.main();
        });
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
          payload: user
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Ahh so simple, my fault.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to use promises. Below is a good tutorial on serial execution of promises. Enclose your methods in promises and run them Promise.all.

https://decembersoft.com/posts/promises-in-serial-with-array-reduce/